# Discord.py put all guild id's into json file

Tags: json, discord.py

is there a way to put all guild ids into a json file, just the id's. I need it for the slash commands.

Comment: there is a couple of things first tell us what you've tried second thing is just put all the guilds using a loop in client.guilds then put it all I guess in a JSON list but just so you know that is not the main use of JSON and besides that JSON is not recommended to store a lot of values safely

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, as a command, but you might want to change it to a loop / task or an event when there's a new guild.

```py
@client.command()
async def guildsid(ctx):
    #SAMPLE_FILE.JSON
    #{"name1": 777703449340143420, "name2": 777703449340143420, "name3": 777703449340143420}
    a_dictionary = {}
    async for guild in client.fetch_guilds():
        a_dictionary[guild.name] = guild.id
    with open("sample_file.json", "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        data.update(a_dictionary)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(data, file)
```